# Can lightweight client implementation of HTTP2 ignore Stream Priority?

Tags: http2

Is **Stream Priority** is an important HTTP2 feature that client implementation should be aware of and obey?

Can client just ignore priorities, ie never create dependent streams and never interpret priority of server streams?

For example Dynamic Table of **HPACK** feature can be disabled as easily as by specifying **SETTINGS_HEADER_TABLE_SIZE** as `0` in the setting frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Priority is a handy feature of HTTP/2, but it is not mandatory. 
HTTP/2 dynamic priorities are a best-effort feature, because the server may receive the priority packets when it is already too late to satisfy the browser's demands.